# Replace the numeric value

Tags: shell

How do we mask the numeric data if the file is in excel format/csv

```
Input.xlsx/Input.csv 
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,B,-98.02
M,N,1003
P,Q,-1025.345

Output.xlsx/output.csv 
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,B,-78.14
M,N,1143
P,Q,-1245.745
```

I want to mask each numeric value to different value dynamically. Instead of original data it has to mask with dummy number in shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with CSV files, not with xlsx files:

```
gawk -F, 'BEGIN{ OFS=","}
          { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
               x=$i; 
               gsub(/[0-9.-]*/,"",x); 
               if(x==""){ $i=rand()*100 }
          } print $0 }'  Input.csv
```

With above script every numeric value is replaced with a numeric value between 0 and 100 (with decimals)

output (example):

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,B,92.4046
M,N,59.3909
P,Q,30.6394
```

You can replace the `rand()*100` with (almost) anything to get another range.

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` loop over all field in the current line
- `gsub(/[0-9.-]*/,"",x)`  Will replace every number (0-9), or `.` or `-` with an empty string (""), effectively leaving an empty string when it's a number.
- `if(x=="")`  When `x` is empty replace the field with a random value.

NOTE: The final piece `} print $0 }'` can also be written as `}}1'`, but I think using the first option is more clear.

EDIT: Keeping negative numbers negative, with (about) the same number of decimals

Create an awk script (i.e. `replace.awk`):

```
function rep(s) {
        sgn = s<0?-1:1
        nbc = int(log(sgn*s)/log(10))+1
        dec = (s-int(s)==0)?0:length(sgn*s-int(sgn*s))-2
        #print "DEBUG" sgn, nbc, dec, "%"nbc"."dec"f"
        return sprintf("%"nbc"."dec"f",sgn*rand()*(10**nbc))
        }

BEGIN{ OFS=","
        srand()
}
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
               x=$i;
               gsub(/[0-9.-]*/,"",x);
              if(x==""){ $i=rep($i) }
  }
}1
```

and do: `gawk -F, -f replace.awk Input.csv`

output should look like this (example):

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,B,-49.73
M,N,5577
P,Q,-551.278
```

The introduced variables with this solution:

- `sgn` The sign of the number (+1 or -1)
- `nbc` Numbers Before Comma  (Comma ==> meant is Decimal separator)
- `dec` Number of digits after Comma (Comma ==> meant is Decimal separator)

Comment: I don't want to remove . or hyphen. I just want to keep negative values as well.

Comment: Try replacing `rand()*100` by `rand()*100-50`. Then you wil get numbers between -50 and +50

Comment: Added an option to make the random number _better_ (whatever _better_ is in this case )

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Is there any way if i have 5 numeric columns i want to edit only 3 numeric columns in the above script can we enhance it by doing this only for specific columns